# QML PyQt update DB on click and update view accordingly

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qtquick2

I'm building a Qt Quick application using PyQt5 to integrate a python application with a QML view. I have a list of items in a database which are reflected in the QML view. At the moment I can click a button and update the database, but I haven't been able to find or figure out how to update the QML component to show the new device after it's been added. What is the best way to do this? Here is my QML code:

```
Page {
height:300
width:300

    ListView {
        id:deviceList
        width: parent.width
        height:300
        model: list_model
        delegate: Item {}
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var l = myClass.items()
            for(var counter in l){
            list_model.append(l[counter])
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id:list_model
    }

    Button{
        text:'my button'
        onClicked: { myClass.add_item() }
    }
}
```

and my Python code:

```
class myClass:
    @pyqtSlot()
    def update(self):
        db.add_item('new item')

    @pyqtSlot(result=list)
    def items(self):
        return db.get_items()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
self.engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
test = myClass()

self.engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("myClass", myClass)
main_qml = 'main.qml'
self.engine.load(QUrl(main_qml))

self.engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is `myClass`? Anyway you should implement editable [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html).

Comment: `myClass` is basically a simplified version of a python class I have that performs reads and writes to my database. Can you explain in a bit more detail how I would use QAbstractItemModel to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You can start from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing). There are lots of examples across the Internet.